# Linux date calculus return odd result for 2 month ago

Tags: linux, date

When I try to get a month before last from today, I run “date --date ‘2 months ago’”.
But I run this command on Jan 31st, it return December.
I think it should return November.

Would you know how to get a month before last with date command?

Added at 17:30 (JST):
If this date calculus written in Python, I will use dateutil and it's expression is natural as below:

```
from datetime import *; from dateutil.relativedelta import *
today = date.today()
twomonthago = today + relativedelta(months=-2)
```

So, I wonder how could I write same manner in bash shell.

Added at 18:05 (JST):
It seems that not only past month, but future month handling is same oddness.

```
$ date --date '+1 month'
Fri Mar  2 17:42:37 JST 2012

$ date --date '+2 month'
Sat Mar 31 17:42:56 JST 2012

$ date --date '+3 month'
Tue May  1 17:42:59 JST 2012
```

February and April are missing.

Comment: both answers have explained what's happening and it's not odd.  `date` is interpreting your requests mathematically, while you're expecting a natural language interpretation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you ask for "2 months ago" on the 31st of January, it is giving you the 31st of November - which doesn't exist, so it wraps to the 1st of December.

You will have to manipulate just the month portion if that is what you want to do.  This will show the month two prior as a number:

```
echo $(( ($(date +%m)+9)%12+1 ))
```

and this will format it as a month name:

```
date --date $(printf "%.2d/01" $(( ($(date +%m)+9)%12+1 ))) +%B
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
It is a bit tricky, but it works good as a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

You could think of 2 months before January 31 as being November 31, except November only has 30 days. Exactly what answer were you looking for?

Comment: If definition of 2 months is equal to 61 days, your comment is true.
But if the month before last from January is December, is it odd?